# can I variate number in '{}' of [ '{:.3}'.format(i)) for i in mylist]?

Tags: python, printing

I have function that prints list in more comfortable way for me.

```
def pr(mylist):
    print ( [float('{:.3}'.format(i)) for i in mylist])
```

Can I also variate number of digits after decimal point? Something like that

```
def pr(mylist,r):
    print ( [float('{:.r}'.format(i)) for i in mylist])
```

For example

```
mylist = [-3.141592653589793, -2.5132741228718345, -1.8849555921538759]
pr(mylist,3) - [-3.14, -2.51, -1.88]
```

Comment: Maybe also post the desired output of an example call to `pr(l,r)`?

Comment: What exactly does the `l` parameter supposed to be? It's not used inside the function.

Comment: sorry, it was for  mylist

Answer (score 2):

Yes, see [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

```
def pr(mylist,r):
    print ( [float('{:.{}}'.format(i,r)) for i in mylist])

pr([1.234567], 3)
# [1.23]
```

Comment: thanks, it was very helpful. I searched in print section(

Comment: @MaximMaxim If this answers your question, please [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it.